# how to disable lightdm(display manager) on Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS

Tags: 16.04, lightdm

How do I disable lightdm(display manager) during bootup of my machine?
I want to bootup to command prompt and not into GUI desktop.
I am using ubuntu 16.0.4LTS

Comment: the answer below worked for me and none of the mentioned answers in the link above actually works !

Comment: The top answer by Bruno Pereira to the duplicate question linked above describes the exactly same steps.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To boot to console:

`sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target`

You must then edit `/etc/default/grub` by removing `splash` from the GRUB command line. (Remember to update GRUB afterward: `sudo update-grub`).

To get to the Unity desktop from the console, you must enter the command:

`sudo systemctl start lightdm.service`

(The usual `startx` command doesn't work with Unity.)

To restore boot to GUI:

`sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target`

Comment: yours is the answer that actually worked for me. thanks